# Replace part of the line in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a line that looks like this:

```
"startTime": "2022:12:03T10:00:00Z",
```

I want to replace the the date with another date 'dtime', assuming file path is all given:

```
sed -i 's/"startTime":".*/"startTime":"'$dtime'",/' $filePath
```

but this does not work. I'm using Mac and wondering if there are any specifics related to Mac.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The Mac version of `sed` requires an argument after the `-i` flag. `sed -i '' ...`

Comment: I tried to add '' as sed -I '' ... but I get the error: sed: can't read 's/"startTime":".*/"startTime":"2022:12:03T11:00:00Z",/: No such file or directory

Comment: Use a lowercase `-i`.

Comment: I did!! it's Mac that's so smart

Comment: BTW, in general, `sed` is the wrong tool for editing JSON; use `jq` or another proper JSON parser instead. (`jq --arg newStartTime "$dtime" '.startTime = $newStartTime' <old.json >new.json` is an example of what this might look like).